# Game Maker - Random Won't Stop

Tags: random, game-maker

I make a project. I want to make randomize number & draw the number result. So, I make `obj_BossText`, which has a draw event & executes a code inside the event. This is the code:

```
randomize();

var ratio = irandom_range(1, 6);
var u7;

u7 = power(ratio, 6);
draw_text(obj_Boss.x, obj_Boss.y,u7);
```

But, the result is, the text won't stop randomizing & keep changing from one number to another. What is wrong? Do I have to stop the random? But, how? Please explain your code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the *Draw Event* is suppose to contain only graphical rendering functions and statements, you are strongly recommended to separate logic from rendering.

Being the *Draw Event* executed `room_speed` times per second, it keeps generating random numbers continuously over the time, and that's another reason to move the variable assignment outside from the *Draw Event*.

I suggest you to edit your `obj_Boss` having a *Create Event* and a *Draw Event* as follow:

```
// Create Event
randomize();
ratio = irandom_range(1, 6);
u7 = power(ratio, 6);
```

and:

```
// Draw Event
draw_text(obj_Boss.x, obj_Boss.y,u7);
```

This way, your random number `ratio` and its power `u7` will be assigned only once, and you will be displaying the value assigned to them. Also, `ratio` and `u7` aren't local variables anymore but instance variables, thus they are accessible by other instances.

You can even save memory space by removing your variable `ratio` and perform the computation on one line only:

```
// Create Event
u7 = power(irandom_range(1, 6),6);
```

That's a legal statement as first `irandom_range()` is executed, and its return value is used as argument for function `power()`.

Comment: It works! Thanks. But, I have another question. It's about draw_text too. So, maybe you want to check it out [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/122005/83636)

Comment: I will. At least', I'll try :)

Answer (score 1):

only run the `irandom_range` once when you start showing the text and store the result in `obj_BossText`

Comment: I just call it once, do I?

Comment: I don't know game maker but I would presume that "draw event" is run every time it has to be drawn.

Comment: No, I think it isn't